What would be the idiomatic way to create a true frequency map in haskell (without using Data.Map)?
I recognize that this question is a bit weird, after all Data.Map seems like a correct data structure to create a frequency map. However I wanted to create a frequency map that is truly only a function.
And I succeeded:
frequencyMap list =
  frequencyMap' list (const 0)
  where
    frequencyMap' [] fun = fun
    frequencyMap' (head : tail) fun =
      frequencyMap'
        tail
        ( \int ->
            ( if int == head
                then 1 + fun int
                else fun int
            )
        )

However, this implementation is obviously lacking in the optimization department. I have a feeling that there is a more elegant way of doing this that uses some funky functional thingamajig to do this.

Why not just return the lookup after making a Map?

You can for example use a binary tree, or some other structure, that structure does not have to be explicitly defined, but still it thus requires working with some acceleration structure.

If you want something more efficient, you need a data structure...like Data.Map.

Even if you want your externally-visible type not to use Data.Map, the idiomatic way is still to use Data.Map internally.
import qualified Data.Map as M

frequencyMap :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int
frequencyMap as = \a -> M.findWithDefault 0 a freqs where
    freqs = M.fromListWith (+) [(a, 1) | a <- as]

One other subtlety: this definition puts its second argument on the right-hand-side of the defining equation. This is a nod to the main extant Haskell implementation, GHC, which will take that as its cue to share freqs between calls with different a arguments, rather than recomputing it each time a different a is supplied.


However I wanted to create a frequency map that is truly only a function.

If you take a function as base-case, there is not much more that you can do besides incrementing the count.
If the keys are orderable, then we can work with a binary tree lookup, like:
toFreq' :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> Int
toFreq' [] = const 0
toFreq' (x:xs) = \y -> if y < x then left y else if y > x then right y else mid
  where left = toFreq' (filter (x >) xs)
        right = toFreq' (filter (x <) xs)
        mid = 1 + length (filter (x == ) xs)

This then allows to work with:
x = toFreq' (concat (replicate 1000000 ([1,4,2,5] :: [Int])))

and lookup with:
x 4

The first time we lookup the value, this will take some processing time, but the next time it will already have optimized the procedure. Eventually result on average (not worst-case) result in O(log n) behavior. By first sorting the list, and thus make an ideal binary tree, we even can guarantee O(log n) behavior.
But regardless, using a data structure like a Map is what you should do to define frequency tables.

Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I understand using Data.Map is better in virtually all situations but I think its cool that you can make a function like that, as an exercise. :3

If you first sort (likely an O(n log n) operation) the data, then you're basically just doing a run-length encoding which is an O(n) operation and doesn't require any data structure fancier than a list of tuples. Of course, lookups will then be O(n) on that rather than O(log n) for something like a map backed by a balanced binary search tree, so there is a price to pay for simplicity.
import Data.List

freq :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
freq = rle . sort
  where
    rle = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group

